Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: mf.pbkdf2 is not a function
Problem with crypto in Chrome Extension for Password Encryption
I'm building a Chrome extension wallet and since i have never implemented/worked with extensions before im testing the flow. I send a password and mnemonic to the background script for encryption, but I'm running into issues when using the crypto API for password-based key derivation (deriveEncryptionKey).
What I'm Trying to Do
I have a form where users submit a password and i generate mnemonic to derive keys with it. I want to encrypt the mnemonic using the password and store it securely.

Here's the flow of the code:


Send password and mnemonic to the background script:

const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    validateRePassword(values.rePassword, values.password);
    try {
        const msg = {
            password: values.password,
            data: mnemonic
        }
        const data = { type: "InIt", value: msg };

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(data, (response) => {
            console.log("Response from background script:", response);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        alert('Error fetching mnemonics: ' + error);
    }
};


Receive the data in the background script and call the setKeyringStore method:

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (msg.type === "InIt") {
        const store = new SecureStore(persistentDB);
        store.setKeyringStore(msg.value.data, msg.value.password);
        return true;
    }
});


Encrypt the mnemonic inside the setKeyringStore method:

async setKeyringStore(json: any, password: string): Promise<void> {
    const plaintext = JSON.stringify(json);
    const ciphertext = await encrypt(plaintext, password);
    await this.setKeyringCiphertext(ciphertext);
}


Encryption function calls deriveEncryptionKey:

export async function encrypt(
    plaintext: string,
    password: string
): Promise<SecretPayload> {
    const salt = randomBytes(16);
    const iterations = 600000;
    const digest = "sha256";
    const key = await deriveEncryptionKey(
        password,
        salt,
        iterations,
        digest,
        secretbox.keyLength
    );
    const nonce = randomBytes(secretbox.nonceLength);
    const ciphertext = secretbox(Buffer.from(plaintext), nonce, key);
    return {
        ciphertext: bs58.encode(ciphertext),
        nonce: bs58.encode(nonce),
        salt: bs58.encode(salt),
        iterations,
        digest,
    };
}


Here's where I derive the encryption key (deriveEncryptionKey):

async function deriveEncryptionKey(
    password: string,
    salt: Uint8Array,
    iterations: number,
    digest: string,
    keyLength: number
): Promise<Buffer> {
    const key = JSON.stringify({ password, salt: Array.from(salt), iterations, keyLength, digest });
    const derive = () =>
        new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) =>
            crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keyLength, digest, (err, key) =>
                err ? reject(err) : resolve(key)
            )
        );

    if (!cache[key]) {
        cache[key] = derive();
    }
    return cache[key];
}

Issue
I initially got an error when calling deriveEncryptionKey. Here's the error message:
 error img 
I suspected the issue was related to crypto not being available in the Chrome extension environment since its for node js, so I tried replacing it with window.crypto, which led to another error saying "window not defined."
As a last resort, I tried the Web Crypto API version with crypto.subtle, but it threw this error:Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties background.js:1 of undefined (reading 'importKey')
also i read that crypto.subtle does not work in insecure environment
and thus im getting

undefined error on importKey
is there a way around this or completely another way that allows me to test functions without having to put it in https

code for crypto.subtle

 error img 

async function deriveEncryptionKey(
    password: string,
    salt: Uint8Array,
    iterations: number,
    digest: string,
    keyLength: number
): Promise<Uint8Array> {
    const enc = new TextEncoder();
    const keyMaterial = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        enc.encode(password),
        { name: 'PBKDF2' },
        false,
        ['deriveKey']
    );

    const derivedKey = await crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
        {
            name: 'PBKDF2',
            salt: salt,
            iterations: iterations,
            hash: digest.toUpperCase(),
        },
        keyMaterial,
        { name: 'AES-GCM', length: keyLength * 8 },
        true,
        ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
    );

    const rawKey = await crypto.subtle.exportKey('raw', derivedKey);
    return new Uint8Array(rawKey);
}





 

